# Does your character possess a magic aura as a wizard while you are incapacitated?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic, wizard, conditions, unconscious

My character was incapacitated (0 HP, passed my death saving throws). My party went on head to the next room without me after failing to revive me. Little did they know the next room was the boss room and they all are now rolling death saves. The boss searches the area for more invaders and is using *detect magic* to look around. Would the boss see my magic aura from my body since I'm a wizard or would me being incapacitated prevent any magic from being seen so he thinks I'm dead?

Me and my D&D group thank you for your help on solving this.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: Would consider this a duplicate, but worth mentioning that whether the wizard is incapacitated or not does not affect the answer given to the other question.